# In google-colab pandas.read_pickle() is not working on pickle5

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, pickle

I made a pickle file of a dataframe from my computer using `pd.to_pickle()` which I could not read in colab. It gives error `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5`. Please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `pickle5` first, using:

```
!pip install pickle5
```

Then,

```
#Import the library
import pickle5 as pickle

path = 'path_to_pickle5'

with open(path, "rb") as dt:
  df = pickle.load(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar problem trying to open a "pickled" pd.dataframe. The solution for me was upgrade the default pandas version of google colab notebook. From 1.3.5 to 1.5.2

`pip! install pandas==1.5.2`

## restart kernel